# data context from router and recipes not showing

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am getting data context from router and recipes are not showing on my recipes page.I want to ask what i am doing wrong here?

**collections.js**

```
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');
```

**router.js**

```
Router.route('/recipes', function () {
    this.render('recipes',{
            name:'recipes'
        },
        {
            data: function(){
            return Recipes.find();
        }
    });
});
```

**recipes.html**

```
<template name="recipes">
    {{#each recipes}}
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-image">
                            <img src="{{image}}" class="panel-image-preview" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h4>{{name}}</h4>
                            <p>{{description}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="vertical-align:middle"></span><small> {{time}}</small></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart " style="vertical-align:middle"></span><small>15 </small></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the collection? Can we see that code?

Comment: here is github link   https://github.com/soni1/foody   @gdataDan

Comment: I think you need to read [http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish "this"). As far as I can tell you are not publishing/subscribing to data in the collection and as is your collection is simply empty.

Comment: I have not deleted default auto publish and insecure packages yet so do not need publish the data at the moment.

Comment: Inside of your recipes page does Recipes.find().count() return a number larger than 0? Also is your sample data, or inserted data, structured like this: {recipes:{name:x,image:y},{name:x,image:y}} etc?

Answer (score 1):

Your route is messed up. You seem to be mixing route options and rendering options in a way that doesn't parse. Also, your data context doesn't have recipes as a field.

Maybe the following is what you wanted?

```
Router.route('/recipes', function () {
    this.render('recipes', {
        data: function() {
            return { recipes: Recipes.find() };
        }
    });
}, {
   name:'recipes',
});
```

Personally I prefer adding the data to route and not the rendering call and use route options when possible:

```
Router.route('/recipes', {
   name: 'recipes',
   template: 'recipes',
   data: function() {
       return {recipes: Recipes.find()};
   }
});
```